# Inline audio play/pause on <a> text link

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Here's what I have so far from piecing together a few different methods I found:

```
http://192.185.121.49/~steveobr/
```

I need all the voice demos to work like the first one "Commercial"

As you can see on the live example, every link is currently tied to the same function. I can write a different function for each line but I assume there is a better way to do this in one function. Here's my code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function playpauseMP3(){
    if(document.getElementById("mp3").paused){
      document.getElementById("mp3").play();
      document.getElementById('audio_text').innerHTML = 'Pause';
    }else{
      document.getElementById("mp3").pause();
    }
  }
</script>

<a id="mp3" title="Play/Pause" onclick="playpauseMP3();" href="#"><span id="audio_text">Commercial</span></a> 
<a id="mp3" title="Play/Pause" onclick="playpauseMP3();" href="#"><span id="audio_text2">Narration</span></a> 
<a id="mp3" title="Play/Pause" onclick="playpauseMP3();" href="#"><span id="audio_text3">Promo </span></a> 
<a id="mp3" title="Play/Pause" onclick="playpauseMP3();" href="#"><span id="audio_text4">TV Affiliate</span></a> 
<a id="mp3" title="Play/Pause" onclick="playpauseMP3();" href="#"><span id="audio_text5">Radio</span></a>
```

Comment: So whats actually your question? :/

Comment: That IP is a private one, no one can connect to 192.185.121.49 unless they are within you LAN.

Comment: all of your a elements have the same id too....although this may work, it's not a good idea to do this!  If you have styling applying against each of them, use a CSS class instead

Comment: Question is - what is the best way to do this with 1 function rather than one function for each audio file.

Comment: It is not a private IP.

Comment: The IDs on the a elements don't matter. I deleted them. However, I am preloading the audio using this code `<audio src="http://192.185.121.49/~steveobr/demos/Country.mp3" id="mp3" preload="auto"></audio>` So maybe there is no way to do this without different functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function playpauseMP3(objAnchor){
   //if(objAnchor.paused){   // anchor tag is not having pause, play and pause methods
       //objAnchor.play();
       objAnchor.firstChild.innerHTML = 'Pause';      
   //}else{
       //objAnchor.pause();
   //}
}


<a id="mp3" title="Play/Pause" onclick="playpauseMP3(this);" audio="song1.mp3" href="#">
    <span id="audio_text">Commercial</span></a> 
<a id="mp3" title="Play/Pause" onclick="playpauseMP3(this);" audio="song2.mp3" href="#">
    <span id="audio_text2">Narration</span></a> 
<a id="mp3" title="Play/Pause" onclick="playpauseMP3(this);" audio="song3.mp3" href="#">
    <span id="audio_text3">Promo </span></a> 
<a id="mp3" title="Play/Pause" onclick="playpauseMP3(this);" audio="song4.mp3" href="#">
    <span id="audio_text4">TV Affiliate</span></a> 
<a id="mp3" title="Play/Pause" onclick="playpauseMP3(this);" audio="song5.mp3" href="#">
    <span id="audio_text5">Radio</span></a>

<div style="display: none;">
<audio src="horse.ogg" controls>
</audio>
```

You can easily get the anchor tag and its child span, And can change the text as well.

For playing audio please [visit here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp) for detail information.

A rough idea to play the different audios using single function is here:

```
function playpauseMP3(objAnchor){
    var audioElement = document.getElementByID('player');
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', objAnchor.getAttribute("audio"));
    audioElement.play();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm currently adding separate functions for each audio file. Will your code allow me to play different audio files for each text link even though each text link is linked to the same function?

Comment: It must allow you. For playing audio you should try this http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_sounds.asp

Comment: Feel free to mark this answer as "Accepted" if you think it answered your question. And this will help the others to know that you are happy with this.